# what version on .net framework do I need to install

Tags: .net

I am running WinXP in VMWare workstation 6.5 and my host OS is Win 7.0, 64 bit.
I need to install a software on this WinXP that needs IIS and .Net Framework . ( 2.0 works with it).
I am on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542
but not sure which one to install? I installed

before posting this question I had installed Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x86)
 but nothing is actually installed.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851 you can use all versions of asp.net on all iis so just download the newest

Comment: @Kim:  
I think .net 4.0 won't install on WinXP SP2. –

Comment: It will be installed i have .net 4.0 on a windows home server 2003...iis 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest framework. (.Net 4.0)

Go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851) and follow the instructions

Hope this helps

Comment: I think .net 4.0 won't install on WinXP SP2.

Comment: It will install on Win XP SP3. Is there any reason why you won't install the latest service pack?